# How to incorporate Open MPI Java Bindings into a Maven Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, mpi, openmpi, cytoscape

I have developed a maven-based plugin (or app) for the open-source bioinformatics Java Application Cytoscape. I was wondering if I could incorporate Open MPI Java Bindings inside this project. My goal would be to execute jobs in parallel in the back and throw multiple network views, graphs etc at the front (so it can be visualized on a visualization wall)

Looking at the [manual here](https://docs.open-mpi.org/en/v5.0.x/features/java.html), I can see how it's built for runnable jar files, but could not find any resource that suggests its incorporation in to a Maven project.

Then I came across this [openmpi java binding dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/openMPI/openmpi-java-binding/1.8.6) from 2015. But, when I tried to do mvn install mpi.jar and add the dependency to my pom.xml, my project went berserk!

All of a sudden, the javax.swing. variables like JButton, JPanel, etc gave the error "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable xyz defined in an enclosing scope". And I hadn't even touched the source code.

So, is there any way to use OpenMPI Java bindings in maven project to achieve the goal I mentioned above?

Comment: This question is unclear. 
Please read [How to Write a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and Show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also [The Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) may be able to help with any other questions using correctly this site.

Comment: Dear @aled can you elaborate what exactly isn't clear? I am basically asking if it is at all possible to use openmpi java bindings in maven-based applications. It's more of a general question rather than "my code is not working and am I getting this error", I could not find anything on the internet related to building OpenMPI in Maven.

Comment: The second question you mention is more suitable for Stackoverflow because is more specific and you can provide reproduction steps and errors. The original question is too broad, we don't have enough context to understand how do you plan to use the component you mentioned or which answers could be acceptable. Than lends to opinion based answers that will be off topic here. This is not a discussion forum to ask opinions. Ask specific questions about specific issues.

Comment: The following links might help you to improve the question: [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Write a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [off-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You've really got two challenges here.  First, how to integrate the openMPI bindings in your app -- you should be able to do that by explicitly listing it as an app dependency in Maven.  If mpi.jar isn't available on any of the standard Maven repositories, you may have to download it and embed it directly.  Checkout some of the Cytoscape apps on my repo (github.com/RBVI) and you'll see some where I've had to explicitly embedded a jar.

The second challenge might be more difficult, which is how to make sure that the openMPI jar files and OSGi work well together.  Not so sure about that.